# GTK equivalent to Control.Controls from System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, gtk3, .net-5, gtk#

I'm trying to find the GTK equivalent of Control.Controls, which is something that is only available in System.Windows.Forms, same thing for ControlCollection.

So I was wondering if anyone knew the GTK equivalent to that, or if there's a solution to making something similar in GTK? Because those functions had features like add and remove, but I'm unable to find anything similar in that regard.

The code that I have with me right now that I wish to change, is this:

```
private void CreatePianoKeys()
        {
            // If piano keys have already been created.
            if (keys != null)
            {
                // Remove and dispose of current piano keys.
                foreach (PianoKey key in keys)
                {
                    Controls.Remove(key);
                    key.Dispose();
                }
            }

            keys = new PianoKey[HighNoteID - LowNoteID];

            whiteKeyCount = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                keys[i] = new PianoKey(this);
                keys[i].NoteID = i + LowNoteID;

                if (KeyTypeTable[keys[i].NoteID] == KeyType.White)
                {
                    whiteKeyCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    keys[i].NoteOffColor = Color.Black;
                    keys[i].BringToFront();
                }

                keys[i].NoteOnColor = NoteOnColor;

                Controls.Add(keys[i]);
            }
        }
```

Because I'm currently trying to change the UI from WinForms to GTK, so it can work on Linux distributions.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but just like in .NET, in GTK, only certain kinds of widgets ("Controls" in .NET-speak) can specify its children (like the `ControlCollection` in your example). These parent widgets are usually objects that derive from the `Gtk.Container` base class, which implements the `Gtk.Buildable` interface.

You can add children to any Container object by using its `Add()` or `Remove()` methods, just like you do with the `ControlCollection` object In C#. Since this is a piano, you could use a `Gtk.Box` (or a subclass of it), which is a container that shows its children widgets in a single row back-to-back if specified as horizontally-oriented. Since I don't know what sort of class your `PianoKey` is, I can't suggest a good alternative in GTK, but hopefully that helps.

Comment: Awesome! I'll definitely give it a go! And PianoKey is a ```private class PianoKey : Widget```, so it uses Gtk.Widget, originally was ```private class PianoKey : Control```, so PianoKey is actually a class that's part of the project itself.

Comment: Yeah, if it's just a `Gtk.Widget` already, you'll do fine with adding it to the `Gtk.Box`. Please make certain to mark this as the appropriate answer if it answered your question, or if it doesn't, come back, and we can discuss in comments. Thanks.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the entire project that I'm moving over to GTK, is actually a library that was made for the WinForms toolbox in designer, so I'm curious, if I want to make it something that can be selected in Glade in the same way as it was with WinForms, will I still need to implement the Gtk.Box or similar?

Comment: Yes. `Gtk.Box` is used in GtkBuilder UI definitions like Glade can produce. The UI definitions are referencing the same widgets that you do programmatically. They are just in a separate declarative file. When you use them, you just load and bind in code.

Comment: Also, I was curious if I can also use SkiaSharp as well? If so, do I need to specify it for the ```Gtk.Box``` in order for the graphics to load? Mostly because it has the names of the colours, and similar functions to what ```System.Drawing``` has.

Comment: I think you'll need to ask in a separate question for that. I am unfamiliar with SkiaSharp. Please mark this answer as solved if I solved the initial question. Thanks.

Comment: I shall, I'm going to ask another question about another GTK function in a separate question, but your answer definitely solved my initial question, thank you so much!